# BC30456: 'CreateResourceBasedLiteralControl' is not a member of 'ASP.staff_hod_site_master'

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

while running my page showing error one error. The error is :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'CreateResourceBasedLiteralControl'
>   is not a member of 'ASP.staff_hod_site_master'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 23:   Line 24:    Line 25:       Line 26:
>
> - This shop requires
>     JavaScript to run correctly. Please activate JavaScript in your
>     browser.
>
> Line 27:

[image]

Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Just hit the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Page directive and make sure it is inheriting the proper file.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Index.aspx.vb" Inherits="Reports_Index" %>
```

And check the partial class too.

```
Partial Class Reports_Index
```

This typically happens if you renamed the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check for other/additional dependencies which you might've missed. The last time I had this error it was because I only deployed the files which were part of my current build, instead of all of the files in my ./bin/ folder.  I looked in my (currently working) dev machine, in the project/bin/ folder and found a few additional files (which were not in my newest build). Once I added those to my server, problem-solved.